# Printing accented characters in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, diacritics

I'm new to python. I'm trying to print accented characters, like this:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    print 'éàÇÃãéèï'
```

But when I execute this code, I get:

```
    >> ├®├á├ç├â├ú├®├¿├»
```

I'm using 64-bit Windows 7 & Python 2.7.5, I have the code in `file.py` and execute it with

```
python file.py
```

Comment: What version of python? (and what's the encoding of the terminal you're printing to?)

Comment: The `coding: utf-8` comment has the *only* purpose of allowing the interpreter to correctly interpret the string literals. It has **nothing** to do with printing or outputting characters. In your case your terminal seems to use a different encoding. Try to check which encoding are returned by `sys.getdefaultencoding` and `sys.stdout.encoding`.

Comment: It works perfect for me and i am using Python 2.7 and also Windows 7 64bit, please provide more details about which version are you using and are you saving it to a file or not?

Comment: Put a `u` at the beginning of the string to mark it as a Unicode string, and make sure the file is actually saved in UTF-8. (Note: you may have to explicitly `.encode()` to your terminal's encoding when printing, although it's possible Python will do the right thing for you this time and only give ugly UnicodeEncodeErrors later when you try to run it elsewhere.)

Comment: Also, make sure you know the **encoding of the py file**; I just got bitten by a Windows file and its `ISO-8859` encoding. Use gedit in Linux (or notepad in Windows) and save the file in `utf8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Wooble mentioned, if you change

```
print 'éàÇÃãéèï'
```

to

```
print u'éàÇÃãéèï'
```

It should work.

Here is a good intro to unicode in python (both for 2.x and 3):
[The updated guide to unicode](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2013/7/2/the-updated-guide-to-unicode/)

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

print('Now it works éàÇÃãéèï')
```

Comment: This is availbale since Python 3.7. Question is titled _Printing accented characters in Python 2.7_